# Does Mac OS have different Git versioning?

Tags: git, macos, command-line, homebrew

I installed Homebrew and Git a few years ago. I'm now going through the steps to reinstall and make sure they're current.

When I do `brew install git`, then `git --version`, it prints: `git version 2.24.2 (Apple Git-127)`.

I don't want this version. It's old. However, when I rerun `brew install git`, an alert appears saying `Warning: git 2.44.0 is already installed and up-to-date.`

Can someone help me understand what's going on? Is it 2.24 or 2.44?

Comment: Maybe 2.24 is the latest version that brew is aware of?  In fact here is a comment on the git downloads page: `Note that any non-source distributions are provided by third parties, and may not be up to date with the latest source release`

Comment: The Git installed by home brew is not the same as the built in Apple Git. You have installed home brew's Git but you are not using it.

Comment: Idk, I don't think that should be the case. The instructions I'm following seem fairly clear that anything less than 2.28 is not good enough, and if I encounter this, "follow the instructions again." I don't know what following the instructions again is supposed to do. Why would the same action produce different results?

Comment: @matt Interesting that these instructions for Mac OS make no mention of that fact. I guess I'll look into that next. Thanks.

Comment: If you have multiple versions installed, the directory order in your PATH matters. Make sure the bin directory for Homebrew comes first. (Not that I recommend using Homebrew at all, but this isn't the right place for rants tangential to the question at hand).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, thank you. Also, I was using OS 14.3.1. I just updated to 14.4.1 and the Mac-installed Git version upgraded too, so I didn't need to go through those steps. I didn't realize Mac's installation and Homebrew's were kept separate.

Comment: Homebrew _can't_ overwrite executables provided by Apple, and neither can any other package manager (the one I use and prefer is [Nix](https://nixos.org/)) -- the root filesystem is read-only on current MacOS releases.